# how to build a view like the default SMS thread view?

Tags: android, view

The SMS thread view is like this:

```
==here is the icon of 'someone'==
someone: xxxxxx
me: xxx
someone: xxxxxx
me: xxx
===here is an editbox== =button=
```

Ok, i hope with the ugly sample above can make my question more clear to you.  As i suppose, the view is not a ListView, either a TextView. It seems the TextView does not support scroll function. And ListView will hightlight the list item when i click it.

I'm not very familiar with GUI programming, so i hope someone can give me some advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to click on each line, then you can still use ListView with `android:clickable="false"` and so it wan't highlight the item.

Also, if you choose to use a TextView, you can wrap it in a ScrollView, to make it scrollable.

Comment: Actually, and 'android:clickable' to my ListView does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to the ListView itself, but to the items(TextView) inside

Comment: I usually define a row_layout in xml, and there you can set the clickable attribut. Maybe you can take a look at this project for a real example: https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Comment: Yes, i add a list_item.xml (RelativeLayout) to define my ListView's item. I put android:clickable="false" to the TextView or to the RelativeLayout (parent viewgroup of TextView), it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you have any error, or it's not the effect you're expecting?

Comment: It's not the effect i'm expecting. I can still select the item and make the item hightlight.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably I didn't really understand what you mean by highlight; maybe it's about android:focusable!? - but I can click and focus on any message in the SMS thread, even if there is nothing happening on click-but this doesn't have to do anything with the layout, but with setOnClickListener().

Comment: The 'highlight' means, when i click an item, the item will become yellow color by defaul. And if i donot click the item, the item is black.  Ok, i donot want to focus on this problem anymore. Maybe the user can click on the item and popup a context menu is a good idea. Thanks anyway, you all are good guys. (Actually i have many other problems to solve)